# How to fix broken image problem on heroku app?

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

Last two days I have stucked with this problem. I have a small heroku app and a small tiny icon called "icon.png" in my "assets" folder on main dir. Here is map of dir:

```
assets
    icon.png
index.html
index.js....
```

So, I refer to icon.png in index.html as this:

```
<span id="logo"><img src="assets/icon.png" id="iconMenu"><a href="/index.html" id="logo-link">articlemoose.co.uk</a></span>
```

I have spent hours over hours to understand what I am doing wrong, I have searched on many similar questions on stackoverflow and other websites but no help.

I will really appreciate any help or idea you might give. Thank you

Comment: This is a case of garden variety debugging. Look in the browser console for the path of the resource that the browser gets the 404 on. Then, go to your code and look at what code is supposed to handle that path. If it's an `express.static()` line of code, then extrapolate from the code and the URL where exactly in your file system `express.static()` would be looking for that file and see if it's there. If you need help with  any of these steps, then add the precise URL from the browser console (that shows the 404 error) and add the relevant server-side code that is supposed to serve that file.

Comment: Also static resources should nearly always be specified in the HTML with absolute URLs with a leading `/` on the path such as `<img src="/assets/icon.png" id="iconMenu">` so they are not dependent upon the path of the containing HTML page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, I will try the ways you mentioned, hope this will solve issue.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: thank you for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 1):

can you check your build folder to make sure the image is there

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using github to auto-deploy to heroku. And on github folder, the image sits there, I just checked now.

Answer (score 0):

I should have added this to my index.js file:

```
app.use("/assets", express.static("assets"));
```